# Why does wrapping setMouseCallback cause Mat object to be empty?

Tags: c++, opencv

I don't understand why wrapping `setMouseCallback` causes the `Mat` object in `onMouse` to be empty while calling `setMouseCallback` directly in `main` does not.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* image = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(param);
    if (image->empty())
        cout << "The image is empty." << endl;
}

void Wrapper(Mat input)
{
    setMouseCallback("Input Window", onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&input));
}

int main()
{
    Mat input = imread("filename.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    namedWindow("Input Window", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Input Window", input);

    // Wrapper(input); // A

    //setMouseCallback("Input Window", onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&input)); //B

    waitKey(0);
}
```

## Edit

The reasoning in [Alexis Wilke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55527832/5482465) makes sense but it might not be 100% correct. In the following code I wrap the whole such that no need to pass `Mat` to the `Wrapper`  but the issue still appears. So what causes this?

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* image = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(param);
    if (image->empty())
        cout << "The image is empty." << endl;
}

void Wrapper()
{
    Mat input = imread("filename.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    namedWindow("Input Window", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Input Window", input);

    setMouseCallback("Input Window", onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&input));
}

int main()
{

    Wrapper(); 

    waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: You still have a dangling pointer even in the second version. You do understand C++ rules for scope and object lifetimes, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasoning is left as unknown but the following solved the issue!

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    Mat* image = reinterpret_cast<Mat*>(param);
    if (image->empty())
        cout << "The image is empty." << endl;
}

void Wrapper()
{
    Mat input = imread("filename.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    namedWindow("Input Window", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Input Window", input);

    setMouseCallback("Input Window", onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&input));

    waitKey(0);
}

int main()
{    
    Wrapper();             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to declare the `Wrapper()` with a reference value, not a value by copy:

```
void Wrapper(Mat & input)
{
    setMouseCallback("Input Window", onMouse, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&input));
}
```

See the additional `&`?

Without the `&`, you pass a copy of you `input` and your original doesn't get modified.

```
Mat input;
Wrapper(input);   // without the `&`, input is copied and whatever happens
                  // to the copy is not known by the caller
```

You could also use a pointer:

```
void Wrapper(Mat * input)
```

although I suspect that you're using a reference to avoid the pointer.

Comment: The beginning of this answer is on the point (passing by reference would solve it), but then it seems to lose it. The copy itself wouldn't be much of an issue given that `Mat` is basically a shared pointer (not to mention OP never modifies it). The fatal problem is the dangling pointer (which you also have in the last snippet). `setMouseCallback` stores the pointer (which is to a local variable). However the callback is dispatched much later (in `waitKey`).

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit, I could not see your edit. I suspect someone deleted it. Anyway, the last part was totally wrong... I removed it completely.

Comment: @DanMašek, Ooops... Correct, I removed that last part. It wouldn't work, even with a static, I don't think it would be useful.